# Can you display milliseconds in the time/date on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, time

I need to time some things, thought it would be nice to do this...

Or maybe a better question: Can the date/time format in the Windows task bar be changed?

Comment: To what degree do you want to change the format?  I don't think you can get it down to milliseconds, and it seems that you can't get seconds to display in the tray either.  There may be some third-party tools to facilitate this, though.

Comment: If you need to time things, you will want something that starts counting from `00:00:00` upon the press of a button. The task bar will most likely not give you accurate results when trying to time things, that's also the reason why it doesn't have milliseconds...

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/429772/101936

Comment: Horloger is dead, and it was a desktop widget not an app. It is a travesty that window has no way to measure time accurately !

Comment: Ok, I found https://sourceforge.net/projects/clock-millisecond/ but it only works at 10 FPS :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the only customizations you can make using the native Windows tray clock. Milliseconds are not available.

- Click the Clock in your Windows 7 system tray and then select "Change date and time settings...":

[image]

- Click "Change date and time...":

[image]

- Click "Change calendar settings":

[image]

- From here you can change your date and time display using the preset Windows 7 format. Select one from the drop-down lists or, if you want something more customized, click "Additional settings...":

[image]

Click the "Additional settings..." button to make other customizations:

[image]

[Source of Information](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/change-system-date-displayed-format-windows-7/)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that, as stated in the last screenshot, seconds can only be displayed in the "long time" format.  The system tray uses "short time".

Comment: Correct, the answer to the question is No, any way you stack it. There probably is some 3rd party software to do it, maybe.

Comment: I can't believe this is the answer, what a terrible answer. I need to display milliseconds, how does this not yet exist. If it really does not exist I'm going to code it and post it as the proper answer here